# How to go about App hosting on Shopify app Store?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

We planning to add our app on Shopify store (for merchants to use)

Some things we need answered if we’re going this route:

1. How should we add a new product to their store?
2. How should we query our donation item from their store?
   a. Via ID (more accurate but simply not sustainable as all donation items will possess unique IDs for each store)
   b. Via title (we need to make our donation item uniquely identifiable)
3. What should we name the donation item?
4. What should the logo be?
5. Do we need a product page?

WE dont know much about it so no idea how it is going to go

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a Shopify app that shops can install so that they can import some product from your organisation. You can read more about different kinds of Shopify app and how to develop them [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps)

I would recommend going down the [remix app template](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/create) route for creating an embedded Shopify app, as this is the easiest way to get an app approved and onto the Shopify app store, but your choice will likely depend on what technology you have used to build the 'app' you mentioned.

You can set the logo of your app in the app listing that you will have to create as part of the process of getting your app approved by Shopify. If you haven't reached this step yet, make sure you've signed up for a [Shopify Partner account](https://www.shopify.com/partners) and then follow [these steps](https://help.shopify.com/en/partners/making-apps) to start creating a Shopify app.

You can find more info on how to implement specific funstionality (such as adding a product to a store) by reading over the [Shopify API documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/product#post-products).